# why does wow.js work only once in next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, css-animations, server-side-rendering, wow.js

I'm using wow.js in my next.js project. I want the element to be shown on scroll with animation.

```
const isServer = typeof window === 'undefined'
const WOW = !isServer ? require('wowjs') : null
useEffect(()=>{
  
    new WOW.WOW({
      live: true
  }).init();
  
    
  },[])

return(<>
      // the element should be shown on scroll(using wow.js)
            <div
                 
              className='hover-up-5 flex w-1/2 lg:w-auto py-4 wow animate__ animate__fadeInUp animated'
             data-wow-delay=".8s"
            
              
            >
//some svg here
</div>
</>)
```

Animation runs on scroll only one time after compiling the code and when I refresh my browser, the element isn't shown with animation.

In another words I don't want the element to be shown with animation whenever I scroll to it, It's ok to show animation on first scroll of the page. But I want to see the animation after refreshing page and scrolling to the element for the first time.

I've tried below solutions, but I still have the same problem:

1-Using `import WOW from 'wowjs'` instead of `const isServer = typeof window === 'undefined'; const WOW = !isServer ? require('wowjs') : null`

2-Using wow.js cdn  instead of adding by npm.

3-Using react-waypoint to use scroll trigger.

Update:

In fire fox It works perfect, but in chrome I still have this problem.